# How to define a notion of Hausdorff homeomorphism?

Tags: metric-spaces, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

A separable metric space is called *fractal* if its Hausdorff and topological dimensions are different.
The Hausdorff dimension is *not* invariant by homeomorphism (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566178/84284)).

**Question**: How to define a natural notion of Hausdorff homeomorphism which would imply that the Hausdorff dimension is invariant by Hausdorff homeomorphism?

*Remark*: By natural I mean not *ad hoc*, otherwise we can just define a Hausdorff homeomorphism as a homeomorphism between two spaces of same Hausdorff dimension, but it is not satisfying...

Comment: A comment by @DanielFisher [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061285/is-the-hausdorff-dimension-invariant-under-homeomorphisms) suggests bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms are what you need.  Are you familiar with this class of maps?

Comment: @EricTowers: not that much but I will look for it. I just found [this reference](http://www.ams.org/journals/ecgd/2015-19-02/S1088-4173-2015-00274-X/S1088-4173-2015-00274-X.pdf) also stating this result (in Introduction) but without proof or reference. I wonder whether there is a reference with a proof or if it is just an exercise. Anyway it is the natural notion I needed, thanks!

Comment: This is indeed just an exercise in following the definition of the Hausdorff measure.